# Exception when retrieving data in DataTable: Expecting 2 value(s) for the key being indexed, but received 1 value(s)

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, datatable

I have this GridView to display data.

```
<dx:ASPxGridView ID="ASPxGridView1" runat="server" KeyFieldName="Line1;Line2" OnRowUpdating="ASPxGridView1_RowUpdating">
    <Columns>
        <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn Caption="Line1" FieldName="Line1" Name="col_Line1" ReadOnly="True" VisibleIndex="1">
        </dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>
        <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn Caption="Line2" FieldName="Line2" Name="col_Line2" ReadOnly="True" VisibleIndex="2">
        </dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>
        <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn Caption="Text" FieldName="Text" Name="col_Text" VisibleIndex="3">
        </dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>
    </Columns>
</dx:ASPxGridView>
```

And suppose I have a DataTable storing the datasource. The DataTable have the following settings about the Keys.

```
DataColumn[] key = new DataColumn[2];
key[0] = DT.Columns["Line1"];
key[1] = DT.Columns["Line2"];
DT.PrimaryKey = key;
```

When I tried to find record in a GridView updating event with ASPxDataUpdatingEventArgs e

```
DataRow row = DT.Rows.Find(e.Keys);
```

I got the errors as title. Is there any wrong setting?
Let me know if any other sample codes need for reference.

Comment: i believe e.Keys will give you the key collection.You have enumerate the keys individually and then use them based on index.

Comment: It works, the problem is solved now. Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks @Arpit.
The problem is solved by using the following codes.

```
object[] keys = new object[2];
keys[0] = e.Keys[0];
keys[1] = e.Keys[1];

DataRow row = dt.Rows.Find(keys);
```

Answer (score 0):

and here is some minor code to generate these from some datatable which you wish to assign primary keys:

```
// C#
var pKeys = new DataColumn[2]; // array
pKeys[0] = dt.Columns[dt.Columns.IndexOf("<first column name goes here>")]; // column 0-based of the table of interest
// if multi-part
pKeys[1] = dt.Columns[dt.Columns.IndexOf("<second column name goes here>")]; // column 0-based of the table of interest
...
...
dt.PrimaryKey = pKeys;
```